# Solidity Error (6160): foundry

Tags: solidity, foundry

while running this code

```
import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FundMe} from "../src/FundMe.sol";

contract FundMeTest is Test{
    FundMe public fundMe;
    
    function setUp() external {
    fundMe = new FundMe();
       
    }

    function testFMinumumDollorIsFive() public {
     assertEq(fundMe.MINIMUM_USD(), 5e18);
        
    }
```

I got this error while testing the contract in the foundry

```
Compiler run failed:
Error (6160): Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given but expected 1.
  --> test/FundMeTest.t.sol:12:14:
   |
12 |     fundMe = new FundMe();
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

please help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the constructor of the `FundMe` contract requires one argument. Search for the word `constructor` in `src/FundMe.sol` and you will see there what is the argument that is required.

Imagine that the constructor requires a uint256 as an argument:

```
constructor (uint256 sessions) ... {}
```

Then your instantiation in your test could look like:

```
...
uint256 sessions = 124;
fundMe = new FundMe(sessions);
...
```